# Coming Soon Mobile App - How do I ask for users email?

Tags: copywriting, input-fields, landing-page, app

I'm creating a landing page for my app which will have an input for user's email if they want to be notified when the app launches. My question is what is the best copy to accompany the email input?

1) "Get notified when the app launches"

2) Join the waiting list (something along the lines of making the app seem as though a lot of people already want it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are on a mailing list then, get notified helps if there's the interest, however:
Thank you for your interest, if you would like, we can register you early for access when the  app is ready.
Also,
Thank's for registering in our newest product, please confirm your email and add us to your allowed list. We'll let you know when we let it shine.
To unsubscribe... etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the first one.. "Get notified" etc. This is straight to the point and can easily be understood as "launch will happen soon. join in now"

You could also use "Request an invite". For a more exclusive tone

"Join the waiting list" may make it appear more attractive, but it also has a slight negative and longer timespan ring to it for some users.. "me, wait? for how long? nooo"

Answer (score 0):

Why not answer this question with science:

Randomly show visitors one or the other, and see which one gets a higher rate of registration.

Since you have a hypothesis that the waiting list concept could be an emotional pull, this could be perfect for an A/B test like this.